# How to identify countries with classic asp?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, globalization

I need to indentify 5 countries (Mexico, Brazil, Colombia, Panama and Argentina).

It's possible using IP, servervariables and classic asp?

or we have a better way to do this? (without great knowledges?)

tks.

Comment: Try [Using geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) and see how far it gets you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi your solution 3 another way

1. **With Cookie** : Default page  for select country. use select cookie write
2. **If you use Membership System**: Sign Up member select country.
3. **Last Solution Use ActiveX companent**

Use ip2location country. [Download](http://www.ip2location.com/ip2location-country.zip)

registry your server
    C:> regsvr32 ip2location.dll

and use code

```
<% 
   ' Create server-side object 
   Set ipObj = Server.CreateObject("IP2Location.Country") 

   ' Initialize IP2Location object 
   If ipObj.Initialize("demo") <> "OK" Then 
       response.write "IP2Location Initialization Failed. 
   End If 

   ' Get visitor's IP address 
   IPaddr = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") 

   ' Detect visitor's country of origin by IP address 
   CountryName = ipObj.LookUpShortName(IPaddr) 

   ' Free IP2Location object     
   Set ipObj = nothing 

   If CountryName = "JP" Then 
       ' Visitor is from Japan 
       ' Redirect the URL to index_jp.htm 
       Response.Redirect "index_jp.htm" 
   Else 
       ' Visitor is not from Japan 
       ' Redirect the URL to index_en.htm 
       Response.Redirect "index_en.htm" 
   End If 
%>
```

[you can examine it for detail](https://www.developerfusion.com/code/3175/redirect-web-visitors-by-country-using-asp-and-com/)

Comment: Hi @Hasan-Fehmi-B - first of all tks for your time and help!! I will test and get a feedback here asap. tks a lot!!